# React Native : How to create .pkpass file

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, passkit, apple-wallet

I am creating one app that has create and add loyalty cards to the apple wallet.

I am creating one pass.json file into root directory of my project
Code for pass.json

```
 {
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passType": "boardingPass",
  "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.jump.juice",
  "serialNumber" : "gT6zrHkaW",
  "teamIdentifier" : "89K99U6GYU",
  "webServiceURL" : "https://example.com/passes/",
  "authenticationToken" : "vxwxd7J8AlNNFPS8k0a0FfUFtq0ewzFdc",
  "relevantDate" : "2012-07-22T14:25-08:00",
  "locations" : [
    {
      "longitude" : -122.3748889,
      "latitude" : 37.6189722
    }
  ],
  "barcode" : {
    "message" : "SFOJFK JOHN APPLESEED LH451 2012-07-22T14:25-08:00",
    "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
    "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
  },
  "organizationName" : "Skyport Airways",
  "description" : "Skyport Boarding Pass",
  "logoText" : "Skyport Airways",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(22, 55, 110)",
  "backgroundColor" : "rgb(50, 91, 185)",
  "expirationDate": "2023-12-31T23:59-07:00",
  "boardingPass" : {
    "transitType" : "PKTransitTypeAir",
    "headerFields" : [
      {
        "label" : "GATE",
        "key" : "gate",
        "value" : "23",
        "changeMessage" : "Gate changed to %@."
      }
    ],
    "primaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "depart",
        "label" : "SAN FRANCISCO",
        "value" : "SFO"
      },
      {
        "key" : "arrive",
        "label" : "NEW YORK",
        "value" : "JFK"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "passenger",
        "label" : "PASSENGER",
        "value" : "John Appleseed"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields" : [
      {
        "label" : "DEPART",
        "key" : "boardingTime",
        "value" :  "2:25 PM",
        "changeMessage" : "Boarding time changed to %@."
      },
      {
        "label" : "FLIGHT",
        "key" : "flightNewName",
        "value" : "815",
        "changeMessage" : "Flight number changed to %@"
      },
      {
        "key" : "class",
        "label" : "DESIG.",
        "value" : "Coach"
      },
      {
        "key" : "date",
        "label" : "DATE",
        "value" :  "7/22",
      }
    ],
    "backFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "passport",
        "label" : "PASSPORT",
        "value" : "Canadian/Canadien"
      },
      {
        "key" : "residence",
        "label" : "RESIDENCE",
        "value" : "999 Infinite Loop, Apartment 42, Cupertino CA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is code i write in my app.tsx file onpress of addCardToWallet

```
const passString = JSON.stringify(boardingPass);


const passBytes = fromByteArray(new TextEncoder().encode(passString));


PassKit.addPass(passBytes).then(() => {
  console.log('Pass added successfully');
}).catch((error: any) => {
  console.log('Failed to add pass:', error);
});
```

I got the error... Failed to add pass:Failed to create pass

I am using [react-native-passkit-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-passkit-wallet).
In this library, there is no method to create a custom pass.
I followed all the steps to create the certificate but there is no way to create .pkpass file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.